# Unable to resolve 2.0: missing requirement [2.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel)

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to start one of my bundles, but as soon as I start it, I get the below exception. I am not sure what the problem is.

### Unable to resolve 2.0: missing requirement [2.0] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel)

dependency:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.10-FINAL</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.10-FINAL</version>
        </dependency>
```

Code:

```
public static Vector read(String fileName)    {


        Vector cellVectorHolder = new Vector();
        try{
            FileInputStream myInput = new FileInputStream(fileName);
            //POIFSFileSystem myFileSystem = new POIFSFileSystem(myInput);
            XSSFWorkbook myWorkBook = new XSSFWorkbook(myInput);
            XSSFSheet mySheet = myWorkBook.getSheetAt(0);
            Iterator rowIter = mySheet.rowIterator();
            while(rowIter.hasNext()){
                XSSFRow myRow = (XSSFRow) rowIter.next();
                Iterator cellIter = myRow.cellIterator();
                //Vector cellStoreVector=new Vector();
                List list = new ArrayList();
                while(cellIter.hasNext()){
                    XSSFCell myCell = (XSSFCell) cellIter.next();
                    list.add(myCell);
                }
                cellVectorHolder.addElement(list);
            }
        }catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace(); }
        return cellVectorHolder;
    }
```

Comment: Why are you using such an old version of Apache POI? What happens when you migrate to something much more recent (and with security fixes!)

Comment: Even I try with LAtest version 4.1.2 but same issue occured

Comment: How are you building your OSGi bundle?